# Adding user to Wheel Group errors out with No such object (32)

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to add a user to the "wheel" group and I keep getting this error message (removed dc entries to mask my company:

```
[root@~]# ldapmodify -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=XXX,dc=XXX" -f usergroupadd.ldif
Enter LDAP Password: 
modifying entry "cn=wheel,ou=groups,dc=XXX,dc=XXX"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
    matched DN: dc=XXX,dc=XXX
```

Now I'm sure many will wonder if the 'wheel' group even exists, and that answer is yes. Adjusted user names for security purposes.

```
[root@~]# getent group| grep wheel
wheel:x:10:USER1,USER2,USER3,USER4,USER5,USER6
[root@~]#
```

And lastly my ldif file with the usergroup add appears to be correct:

```
[root@~]# cat usergroupadd.ldif 
dn: cn=wheel,ou=groups,dc=XXX,dc=XXX
changetype: modify
add: memberuid
memberuid: USER7
```

So my question is, what is causing the No such object (32) error?

Thanks,

Comment: One thought that came to mind is maybe I need to load the existing wheel group into LDAP and then start adding/subtracting from it. Might that be the issue?

Comment: `wheel` exists in the group database yes but this a Unix context, are you sure the entry actually exists in ldap ? run `ldapsearch -x -b 'cn=wheel,ou=groups,dc=XXX,dc=XXX' -s base '(objectclass=*)'`

Comment: That was it Eric, I needed to create a wheel group and load that into ldap. I was taking the assumption that the preexisting wheel group could be modified.  Thanks for the sanity check.